# Retrieving version of the product

Tags: wix, wix3.7

During upgrade, I can use  to determine ProductId that installed on the machine.
Is there a way to know the version, like 1.0.0.0, in addition without handling that by yourself, storing in registry etc.

Comment: You can use the version of product which is displayed in the Add or Remove Programs Control Panel. Check the registry key: `[HKLM]\Software\[Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{product code}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Upgrade Version](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_upgradeversion.htm) element. Using this element you can specify things like range of versions for which upgrades are allowed or range of versions for which upgrades are not allowed.

You can also read through this [post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/15/from-msi-to-wix-part-8-major-upgrade.aspx) for a detailed explanation of how upgrade works.